# Probabilities for rolling multiple dice and getting one number or greater

Tags: probability, dice

I am interesting in producing a table of probabilities for dice rolls. These are standard 6 sided dice. What is the probability that for rolling X dice, Y dice will roll (hit) at least number Z or higher.

To hopefully simplify, I would like to fill out the following table. *edit - Table has been filled out thanks to amd's answer. Thanks!

```
                    EXACT Probabilities
#dice|# "hits"| # to roll or higher!
(X)  |  (Y)   |     (Z)
     |        |   2    |   3    |   4    |   5    |   6
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |1       | 83.33% | 66.67% | 50.00% | 33.33% | 16.67%
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2    |1       | 27.78% | 44.44% | 50.00% | 44.44% | 27.78%
2    |2       | 69.44% | 44.44% | 25.00% | 11.11% |  2.78%
--------------------------------------------------------------------
3    |1       |  6.94% | 22.22% | 37.50% | 44.44% | 34.72%
3    |2       | 34.72% | 44.44% | 37.50% | 22.22% |  6.94%
3    |3       | 57.87% | 29.63% | 12.50% |  3.70% |  0.46%
--------------------------------------------------------------------
4    |1       |  1.54% |  9.88% | 25.00% | 39.51% | 38.58%
4    |2       | 11.57% | 29.63% | 37.50% | 29.63% | 11.57%
4    |3       | 38.58% | 39.51% | 25.00% |  9.88% |  1.54%
4    |4       | 48.23% | 19.75% |  6.25% |  1.23% |  0.08%
--------------------------------------------------------------------
5    |1       |  0.32% |  4.12% | 15.63% | 32.92% | 40.19%
5    |2       |  3.22% | 16.46% | 31.25% | 32.92% | 16.08%
5    |3       | 16.08% | 32.92% | 31.25% | 16.46% |  3.22%
5    |4       | 40.19% | 32.92% | 15.63% |  4.12% |  0.32%
5    |5       | 40.19% | 13.17% |  3.13% |  0.41% |  0.01%
--------------------------------------------------------------------
6    |1       |  0.06% |  1.65% |  9.38% | 26.34% | 40.19%
6    |2       |  0.80% |  8.23% | 23.44% | 32.92% | 20.09%
6    |3       |  5.36% | 21.95% | 31.25% | 21.95% |  5.36%
6    |4       | 20.09% | 32.92% | 23.44% |  8.23% |  0.80%
6    |5       | 40.19% | 26.34% |  9.38% |  1.65% |  0.06%
6    |6       | 33.49% |  8.78% |  1.56% |  0.14% |  0.00%
```

```
                    Cumulative Probabilities
#dice|# "hits"| # to roll or higher!
(X)  |  (Y)   |     (Z)
     |        |   2    |   3    |   4    |   5    |   6
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |1       | 83.33% | 66.67% | 50.00% | 33.33% | 16.67%
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2    |1       | 97.22% | 88.89% | 75.00% | 55.56% | 30.56%
2    |2       | 69.44% | 44.44% | 25.00% | 11.11% |  2.78%
--------------------------------------------------------------------
3    |1       | 99.54% | 96.30% | 87.50% | 70.37% | 42.13%
3    |2       | 92.59% | 74.07% | 50.00% | 25.93% |  7.41%
3    |3       | 57.87% | 29.63% | 12.50% |  3.70% |  0.46%
--------------------------------------------------------------------
4    |1       | 99.92% | 98.77% | 93.75% | 80.25% | 51.77%
4    |2       | 98.38% | 88.89% | 68.75% | 40.74% | 13.19%
4    |3       | 86.81% | 59.26% | 31.25% | 11.11% |  1.62%
4    |4       | 86.81% | 59.26% | 31.25% | 11.11% |  1.62%
--------------------------------------------------------------------
5    |1       | 99.99% | 99.59% | 96.88% | 86.83% | 59.81%
5    |2       | 99.67% | 95.47% | 81.25% | 53.91% | 19.62%
5    |3       | 96.45% | 79.01% | 50.00% | 20.99% |  3.55%
5    |4       | 80.38% | 46.09% | 18.75% |  4.53% |  0.33%
5    |5       | 40.19% | 13.17% |  3.13% |  0.41% |  0.01%
--------------------------------------------------------------------
6    |1       | 100.00%| 99.86% | 98.44% | 91.22% | 66.51%
6    |2       | 99.93% | 98.22% | 89.06% | 64.88% | 26.32%
6    |3       | 99.13% | 89.99% | 65.63% | 31.96% |  6.23%
6    |4       | 93.77% | 68.04% | 34.38% | 10.01% |  0.87%
6    |5       | 73.68% | 35.12% | 10.94% |  1.78% |  0.07%
6    |6       | 33.49% |  8.78% |  1.56% |  0.14% |  0.00%
```

---

Edit: I have filled out my table above with @amd's proposed solution. Also, below is some more background information and my work so far. The game my friends and I are playing is Zombicide. In the game, you acquire different weapons, that have different statistics. A weapon rolls a certain number of dice, and hits on a certain roll of the dice or higher. So one weapon may roll 6 dice, but hit on only 5 and 6's, while another weapon may roll only 2 dice, but hits on 3, 4, 5, and 6's. My goal is to use the most effective weapon given the number of targets I want to hit.

When searching Google, I had originally found [this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4KVv.jpg) depicting the odds. But I wanted to know the math involved as well.

My first work was to find the math to hit with one dice roll. I knew a hit of 6 would be a 16.7% probability. A hit of of 5 or 6 would be a 33% possiblity (16.7 + 16.7). Each additional dice face gives you an additional 16.7% chance to hit. I got stumped when trying to extrapolate this out for multiple dice.

What I ended up producing myself was an average number of hits table. I did this by taking the chance any particular die would hit and adding them together.  So if you rolled 6 dice, hitting on 5 and 6's would on average get 0.66 hits. If you rolled 2 dice, and hit on 3, 4, 5, 6, you would average 1.33 hits.

```
  # |   hits on this +
dice|2   |3   |4   |5   |6   
    |----|----|----|----|-----
1   |0.83|0.67|0.50|0.33|0.17
2   |1.67|1.33|1.00|0.67|0.33
3   |2.50|2.00|1.50|1.00|0.50
4   |3.33|2.67|2.00|1.33|0.67
5   |4.17|3.33|2.50|1.67|0.83
6   |5.00|4.00|3.00|2.00|1.00
```

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.

Comment: @JKnecht Thanks, that is good to know. I tried to leave this question pretty generic because I once had a question closed on the Super User Stack Exchange as "too specific." I'll add more to the question tomorrow.

Comment: @Masacroso I believe these are different questions. The question you linked discussed summing dice while I am looking for the number of occurrences at or above a set number.

Comment: You want **exactly** Y dice to roll **at least** Z ?

Comment: As you’ve found, the expected number of successes for the binomial distribution has a very simple formula, which you can verify by either summing things up the hard way or by taking advantage of linearity of expectation. You might want to add the probability of $0$ hits to your tables for completeness.

Comment: In my Excel spreadsheet, I do have a row for 0 hits. However, I've hidden that row by default, because in the board game the players aren't interested in getting 0 hits. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly standard application of the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), which is in fashion in games these days. It gives the probability of getting exactly $k$ successes in $n$ trials as $$
\binom n kp^k(1-p)^{n-k},
$$ where $p$ is the probability of a single trial succeeding.

In your case, the number of trials $n=X$, the number of dice that you’re rolling, and the probability of success $p$ is the probability of rolling $Z$ or higher, namely, $\frac{7-Z}6$.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. I have updated my question to provide tables for both cumulative and exact probabilities. Could you please double check my work? If it looks OK, I will accept this answer. Thank you!

Comment: I double checked my results with the one I linked to in my edit. They were the same. This is the correct answer.